# MS Access - Modify data in Form and save record

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple question but somehow I just couldn't find a proper solution online.

In a form there is a text box. It gets its data via dlookup from a table.
With a button I want to allow editing by setting

```
Me!AllowEdits = True
```

So save there is a button with the code

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

Anyway - by clicking the editing button I'm not able to modify the text written in the text box.

Comment: If the textbox is bound to the DLookup expression (like `=DLookup(..)`), it is read-only.

Comment: It is - how can I change this? @Gustav

Comment: Think about it. What is it you want to change? If you wish to change the looked up value, you must have a (popup) form that is bound to the table you use in the DLookup expression.

Comment: OK, so I could add a button next to the text box which says edit or something like that which will open a popup where I can edit the name?

Comment: Perhaps. Actually, we don't know what you wish to save and where.

Comment: I think I got my solution - I want to write data from text boxes into the tables behind my form. The best way seems to use sql querys.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using DLookup()?

The acCmdSaveRecord command will not save calculated data. This value returned by DLookup() will not be saved to table without first running code to save it into a field, like `Me!fieldname = Me.textboxname`. So you can have another textbox BOUND to that field and that textbox can be editable.